# retag: composer-php as master for composer

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

"Composer" is a great new PHP software for managing dependencies, so naturally questions get to SO and get tagged. The first tag was [composer-php](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composer-php/synonyms), which sounds like the right thing, but people are lazy and invented [composer](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composer/info) as well.

The synonym has already been suggested, but I lack the amount of tag reputation to support it. The description of the two tags is already almost the same.

It would be great if these two get merged.

Comment: 78 questions is still manageable for a manual retag.

Comment: Argh... sorry, thought I'd successfully kept that one dead.  It's now on my list of **57** tags I regularly check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[composer](/questions/tagged/composer) is now a tag with 0 questions. It'll be auto-deleted overnight with the next empty tag purge.

I've manually retagged the 78 questions; for a small number of questions this is something you can easily do yourself. :-) There was *one* non-PHP question, but it was also a closed as Not a Real Question so I had no qualms removing the tag from that post too.

Comment: I was under the impression that manually retagging those is NOT the thing to do because people will come up with the "wrong" tag again later.

Comment: A mod also approved the synonym that was pending votes; normally users of the tags would vote on the synonym and make this kind of thing go away. If people abuse a specific tag too often we can also have it blacklisted but that's a very heavy-handed operation.

Comment: Yes, thanks anyone who was involved. Everything is fine now. :) The problem with rarely used tags and even rarer synonyms is that there barely is a chance to accumulate enough reputation to approve to make this happen user-driven, I think.